# Where does CS0012 get its information from?

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors, compiler-construction

I have a C# application, based on version 84 of a certain DLL.

I have downgraded that DLL and now I'm using version 83. I have done this by replacing the following line in the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<!-- <Reference Include="Firmware.Internal, Version=1.0.84.1,
                             Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Product.Core.22.1.25.3\lib\Firmware.Internal.dll
  </HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference> -->
<Reference Include="Firmware.Internal, Version=1.0.83.1, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Product.Core.16.12.6.1\lib\Firmware.Internal.dll
  </HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

This seems not to work, because of the following line in my source code:

```
Firmware.Internal.InternalGroup dockInternal = ...
```

The error message is:

> The type 'InternalGroup' is defined in an assembly that is not
> referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Firmware.Internal,
> Version=1.0.84.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

This is correct indeed: for version 84 this was working, and for version 83 this is not, so I should upgrade to version 84 in order to make it work.

**Question**: how does the compiler know that? I have removed the reference to version 84, so how can the compiler know that, in order to access that `InternalGroup`, version 84 is the one to be used (why not 85, 86, 136, ...)?

Remark: I have just deleted the commented lines (`<!-- ... -->`)in the `*.csproj` file and the result is equal, so the compiler is definitively not getting that information from that comment.

**Edit:**
P.s.:
I've just deleted the "bin" and the "obj" directories, no differences, so the information is not found in some lingering old compiled binaries neither.

Comment: Unusual question but an interesting one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still may have a reference to version 84 in other projects inside the solution. Check if it is the case, downgrade all projects and rebuild all.